# What's the difference between "Ива́нович" and "Ивано́в"?

Tags: выбор-слова, этимология, выбор-имени, суффиксы

Are both Ива́нович and Ивано́в derived from the given name Ива́н (Ivan)? Ивано́в is a surname, how about Ива́нович?

Comment: Related: [Name suffixes -ов, -ич](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/15794/name-suffixes-%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d1%87)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Иванович** in Сергей Иванович Иванов is a patronymic. Every Russian has a name, a patronymic and a surname, which are used in all official papers. The patronymic means **the son/daughter of** and is formed from one's father's name: Иванович is Ivan's son, Ивановна is Ivan's daughter. So Сергей Иванович's father is/was named Иван.

The endings -ович, -евич, -ич are used to form patronymics for men. For women, the endings are -овна, -евна, -ична. (Петрович, Сергеевич, Ильич, Петровна, Сергеевна, Ильинична)

Answer (score 7):

V.V. forgot to mention that the endings -ович,-евич,-ич, beside being patronymics, can also form surnames.
There's usually a change in stress **Ива́нович** vs **Ивано́вич** or **Си́дорович** vs **Сидоро́вич**, but not always.

For example [Иванович Бранислав](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87,_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2):
Брани́слав — name
Ива́нович — surname.

[Петрович Борис Петрович](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87,_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87):
Борис — name
Петрович — patronymic
Петрович — surname

Russian standard orders are:
[surname] [name] [patronymic]
[surname] [name]
[name] [patronymic]

But Russian also uses the English order: [name] [surname] or [name] [patronymic] [surname]

So **Александр Иванович** is usually **[name] [patronymic]**, but very rarely will it be **[name] [surname]**