# What's the difference between the surname suffix -ов and patronimics in -ич?

Tags: этимология, выбор-имени, суффиксы

Are the suffixes **-ов** and **-ова** in people's names equivalent to the suffix *-son* used in Germanic languages?

The suffixes **-ич**, **-ича** also refer to the name of the father in patronymics. Are they equivalent to *-son* (and *-dóttir* in Icelandic), however used in the *отчество* rather than the *фамилия*?

Comment: IIRC the ending **ович/овна** follows hard consonants. **евич/евна** is the corresponding "soft" ending.

Comment: -ов(а), -ев(а) are originally possessive suffixes that signify your "belonging" to... whatever: a person, a family, a place, etc. In rural areas of Russia it is still fairly common to ask a person (especially a child): "Ты чей?" ("Who [what family] do you belong to?")

Comment: Note that some Slavic surnames may end in -ич (both for males and females), but they are SURNAMES, not patronymics. Example: Анна Петровна Янукович - her surname is the 3rd word, the patronymic is the 2nd implying her father is Петр. Often some -ич surnames may be Jewish.

Comment: Related https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14025/what-is-the-difference-between-%d0%98%d0%b2%d0%b0%cc%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%87-and-%d0%98%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%cc%81%d0%b2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say for **-ов, -ова** a closer analogy (grammatically speaking) would be surnames like Jones, Peters (in the sense that they refer to Jone's, Peter's children. An obsolete Russian form would be *Иванов сын - son of Ivan*, hence the modern surname *Иванов*, where it kind of lost its original *son* part). It just happens that **-son** names are popular in Germanic languages, while **-ов** is very popular in Russian. That's why it may be perceived as an equivalent.

As for patronymics, the correct forms (depending of the stem) are **-ович/-евич/-ич** (male), **-овна/-евна/-ична/-инична** (female) - e.g. Петрович, Петровна. In modern Russian, these forms derive directly from the father's name (interestingly enough, even if the father is unknown or has a non-Russian name, *some* patronymic will be used in their passport, maybe with some rare exceptions), so the name of the father is clear from them. I wouldn't say it's full equivalent of *-son,* because the name ending in *-son* says nothing about the father, whereas the Russian patronymic does.

Comment: It looks like *son* and *'s* are equivalent in English surnames. There are Millersons and Smithsons, for example. But indeed *-ов* is more similar to *'s* grammatically as they both are not words on their own.